# Am I measuring this milling insert wrong?

Tags: tools

A while back I bought a box of "stuff" for my shop and way later found in the bottom of it a 1.625" insert mill with 2 square inserts. It turns out that this produces a really nice cut for what I'm doing. But one of those inserts has only a single good point on it, so I'm trying to get replacements.

As best I can tell, the inserts should be ANSI `SCxx-33x` inserts, probably `SCMT-331`. However I have yet to find **any** source for that insert type. The closest I can find is `SCMT-3(2.5)1`, but I don't think that would fit in the mounting hole.

Do I have some oddball size that is extremely rare? Or maybe obsolete? Of is it more likely that I'm just measuring things wrong?

Or does anyone know of a source for that insert type?

---

The inserts I have measure in as:

- edge length: 0.368"
- Thickness: 0.187"
- back edge length: 0.322-0.325"

Comment: Find a cutting tool supplier.

Comment: Please edit your question's title into something that tells what the question is about. You'll attract readers that know about the topic then.

Comment: @SolarMike As in the online ones I've been looking at? Or as in the retail ones that are 90+ miles away? (I.e. If I could do that I would have already done so.)

Comment: Industrial supply, https://www.mscdirect.com and others. Call or email them questions.